# can my docker container app access the client's microphone and speaker? (Windows)

Tags: firefox, audio, containers, alpine-linux, microphone

I'm building a firefox container application with linuxserver/firefox.
I have a voice and can use the speaker, but I don't have a microphone and I can't use the microphone in online meetings.My Firefox operating system image is Alpine
Is there a way I can use the microphone in my container?
Could someone give me a solution base on container firefox to get access to the microphone and speaker? If I miss any necessary detail for you, please let me know.

sudo apt-get install -y alsa-base alsa-utils

and running the docker image with the following parameters:

docker run --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd <container_name>